# Withdrawing conference submission before notification

Tags: conference, withdraw

Is it unethical thing?
It's been a week since submission and a month left until the final decision.
I'm so worried about it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can withdraw it. There is no issue. The paper is yours. With a month to go you will cause little disruption.

Sooner is better, though.

Comment: Thanks. I was so nervous about it.